# Создание своеобразных "линий" в небольшом блоке

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть небольшой блок в макете. И мне нужно реализовать как-то линии, которые в примере. Пробовал с transform "поиграть" - толком ничего не вышло. Что порекомендуете?

[image: блок-кейс]

Comment: Подложить картинку нельзя? Вопрос только с CSS?

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, если нет рационального решения по CSS, тогда картинкой можно. Пока такового решения не нашёл, и кажется всё же придётся подкладывать.

Comment: @Felix "Своеобразные линии" это контуры желтого прямоугольника с закругленными уголками?

Comment: @Alexandr_T, нет, линии сбоку(отредактировал вопрос): http://savepic.org/8701364.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер!

А почему у Вас с `transform` не получилось?

Вот как у меня получилось реализовать подобную идею https://jsfiddle.net/x2pwzujk/2/. Хотя может действительно лучше использовать изображение, чтобы лишний раз не нагружать браузер.

Comment: Элементы не состыковывались и часто выпадали за пределы. Вы тоже считаете, что лучше изображение? Хорошо, пожалуй на них и сделаю. Спасибо.

Comment: @Felix cудя по скриншоту это некий баннер и мне кажется, что просто нету смысла заморачиваться с полосками вырисовывая их в css. Тем более если таких баннеров на странице будет много, это будет "напрягать" браузер. Вполне достаточно фонового изображения.

Comment: Не совсем баннер. Это элементы страницы. Да, их действительно много будет: http://savepic.org/8700343.jpg
Спасибо за рекомендации!